# Sending data from parent to child prop returns a value then undefined functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-props, react-functional-component

In the main dashboard component i do get requests for 5 arrays. When I log them into the console i get the data.
When I try to pass down the data to a child component the values get undefined then values then undefined

The dashboard;

```
const [logdata, setLogData] = useState([])
const [storageData, setStorageData] = useState([])
const [logquotation, setLogQuotation] = useState([])
const [storageQuotation, setStorageQuotation] = useState([])
const [productQuotation, setProductQuotation] = useState([])

const getLogData = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/logisticsrecords")
    .then(res => {
        setLogData(res.data)
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

const getStorageData = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/storageshipment")
    .then(res =>{
        setStorageData(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

const getLogisticsQuotation = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/logisticsquotation")
    .then(res =>{
        setLogQuotation(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

const getStorageQuotation = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/storagequotation")
    .then(res =>{
        setStorageQuotation(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

const getProductQuotation = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/productquotation")
    .then(res =>{
        setProductQuotation(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}


useEffect(() => {
    getLogData()
    getStorageData()
    getLogisticsQuotation()
    getProductQuotation()
    getStorageQuotation()
}, [])
console.log("dashboard data",logdata, storageData, storageQuotation, logquotation)
```

At this point when i log all the states to the console i get the values as expected.
Passing the values as props to the child component

```
 <DashboardHome 
   storage={storageData} 
   logistics = {logdata}
   storeQuotation = {storageQuotation}
   prodQuotation = {productQuotation}
   logisticsQuotation = {logquotation}
    />
```

Destructuring the values at the child component

```
const DashboardHome = ({  storage,  logistics,  storeQuotation, prodQuotation, logisticsQuotation }) => {

console.log("The dashboard logistics/storage",storage, logistics)
console.log("the dashboard [quotation] data", storeQuotation, prodQuotation, logisticsQuotation)

console.log(storage, "storage data")
console.log("variable length is", storage)
return(...)}
```

What I get at the console
[image]

Comment: are you calling `setStorageData` somewhere else ?

Comment: When doing several async requests, you will get the results in an unpredictable order, so some of the state variables will be undefined

Comment: Also, you are not protecting the situation that the parent will be unmounted. Read about the return function of useEffect

Comment: @Olivier No I have not

Comment: Do you really need 5 requests to display the issue in its minimal form, or does it also happen with 1 or 2 requests? It feels like you are overcomplicating the minimal example.

Comment: I wanted all get request in this parent component (Dashboard) so that they are not scattered all over the children

Comment: When setting state inside useEffect, you need to put the state variable into the dependency array of useEffect. I suspect some values are undefined because the jsx is rendered before the promises are resolved (and the state is set)

Comment: Or you could try to await the responses inside useEffect, then set state inside useEffect (not in `then` callback)

Comment: I used this APIs and the same code of yours and did not got value undefined in the child component. 
1>axios.get('https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user?limit=10', {headers: {'app-id': '6112dc7c3f812e0d9b6679dd', }}) 
2>axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
3>axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
4>axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/unknown') 5>axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/unknown')